# Choosing right live tile type

Tags: windows-phone-8, live-tile

I'm a bit confused about what kind of tile I should choose to make my scenario work.

Scenario is as follows: my application supports small and medium tiles. By default in both these modes it shows an app icon on transparent background but user can choose a particular image to be a tile cover. When tile is covered with image I don't want it to flip or move - just a static image with app name on top of it.

I've tried `TemplateCycle` with app icon as default and user's selected image as an alternative but cycle tile moves these images up and down all the time and I don't want that. I've was considered `TempalteIconic` but it turned out it only supports images with transparent background so no option for user's image. So what kind of tile should I choose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a normal fliptile but don't set anything(text, image) on the back. It won't flip if you do that.